# Can an admin template be used in a Ruby on Rails web app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates

I have been doing UI research and have come across admin templates at http://themeforest.net/. I was wondering how do you apply these onto a web app built on Rails. These templates look very similar to wordpress themes. Are they that easy to configure? Is it just as simple as setting up a link to the database to make the fields form capture data? I've been looking at [this theme](http://themeforest.net/item/pastel-dashboard-admin-template-iphone-web-app/1694914).

Answer (score 0):

For admin templates I recommend using [Active Admin](http://activeadmin.info/). It's relatively easy to implement and gives you great admin screens with little effort.

Comment: he's not looking for an admin theme, he wants to integrate a theme he already found into his app.

Comment: Active Admin is a great project though, I use it myself.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can. I'm trying to solve the same problem and so far I have a couple options:

1.) do it by hand, I've done this before, it works but takes a lot of time to truly understand how your theme is put together. First I would recommend using the included themes assets exactly as they are bundled with the theme. Don't assume that just because you have twitter-bootstrap-rails gem that the bootstrap classes in the theme will work. Link the assets statically and slowly extract out the static assets and replace them in the asset pipeline once you know they work.

2.) Use the strategy suggested in the install_theme gem (http://drnicwilliams.com/2009/10/06/install-any-html-themetemplate-into-your-rails-app/) the gem itself is not maintained any longer (i'm not sure about any forks), but the strategy is sound. Extract the core parts of the template into partials.

The short answer is yes, but there is no straight forward way to "import to rails"